# failure to load css file when I type in domain

Tags: html, css, node.js, server, digital-ocean

I'm getting the message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" on my css file. My site is a node app hosted on a Digital Ocean server

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Brand Central Network</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>www.brandcentralnetwork.tv</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your folder structure for css is public/css/style.css ?

Comment: This looks to me like a reverse proxy issue. Can you share your nginx configuration for the node.js app?

Comment: Hi Jacob here is my nginx config ```javascriptserver {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/brandcentralnetwork.tv/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name brandcentralnetwork.tv www.brandcentralnetwork.tv;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}```

Comment: Hi Prasanta my folder structure is css/style.css, public is my static file folder